# Rename characters within a specific file using find and variables?

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I have a file that looks like the following:

`/var/www/html/media/2018@03@01@vi_0005_20180301_110203.h264.v0005.th.jpg`.

I would like to find this file in `/var/www/html/media` and rename `h264` to mp4 within a bash script that is run from a different folder.

My variables are:

```
mediapath="/var/www/html/media"
filemp4=vi_0005_20180301_110203.mp4
fileh264=vi_0005_20180301_110203.h264
```

I've tried the `rename` command (which works without variables), but it complained when using them. I'm also not sure how to make it look in the media folder.

```
rename 's/${fileh264}/${filemp4}/' *${fileh264}*

Global symbol "$mediapath" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $mediapath"?) at (user-supplied code).
Global symbol "$fileh264" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fileh264"?) at (user-supplied code).
Global symbol "$mediapath" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $mediapath"?) at (user-supplied code).
Global symbol "$filemp4" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $filemp4"?) at (user-supplied code).
```

I've also attempted to use `find` and `mv`, but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

```
find ${mediapath} -name "*${fileh264}*" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/${fileh264}/${filemp4}}' {} \;
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, of course, thanks! My solution then is as follows: `rename "s/${fileh264}/${filemp4}/" ${mediapath}/*${fileh264}*`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is I needed double quotes:

```
rename "s/${fileh264}/${filemp4}/" ${mediapath}/*${fileh264}*
```

Comment: Tell us this is perl's rename, can be another command on some distros

Answer (score 0):

Quoting can be a wired thing on bash.

You should keep in mind, that a singlequote does not interpret anything. 
A `$` is interpreted as an ASCII `$` and not as the beginning of a variable.

You can combine different ways of quotes to reach different goals. I would recommend to check the following link and read "Strong Quoting" section. 
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

As @allemtura said, the correct way is to use doublequotes to interpret the variables correctly.